# AD Certification Authority not issuing new certificates

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

I have a Windows 2003 AD server with Certification Authority issuing certificates onto our network via a WAP. The Certification Authority has stopped doing this without any reason as far as I can see.

All laptops can connect unless there certificate has expried so its not a problem with the certificate.

There is no Revoked Certificates, Pending Requests or Failed Requests.

When looking at the certificate the message says "This certificate has expired or is not yet valid"

Any help would be great, even if its just were to find the logs for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed the problem. Even though its already on SP2 for some reason the CERTSVC_DCOM_ACCESS group wasnt created... go figure!

Anyways created the group and its all working now.

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;903220

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the root certificate has expired?

Have a read here, it's a pretty good thread with lots of fact about expiration:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserversecurity/thread/9853af03-07a4-4048-8d27-a8f5b7105afb

Answer (score 0):

Open the Certificate MMC on the server and inspect the certificates there. Do the same on a laptop. If there are problems such as expired certificates, you should see it there.

Examine eventlogs on both server and clients to get more information on errors.

Also, an ActiveX control was deprecated in Windows Vista clients and Windows Server 2008, look here for an update: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922706
(not sure if it's relevant in your environment..?)

Comment: The root certificate hasnt expired, I can still request a new certificate through MMC\Certificates(Current User) just not through Certificates(Local Computer)

Event Log states Automatic certificate enrollment for local system failed to enroll for one Computer certificate (0x80070005). Access is denided